# Trouble understanding the explanation of "server certificate" message in RFC 5246?

Tags: tls, certificates

The following texts are found in the explanation of "Server Certificate" message in the [RFC 5246 TLS 1.2](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-5246.txt) at page 46.

```
7.4.2.  Server Certificate
```

When this message will be sent:

```
  The server MUST send a Certificate message whenever the agreed-
  upon key exchange method uses certificates for authentication
  (this includes all key exchange methods defined in this document
  except DH_anon).  This message will always immediately follow the
  ServerHello message.
```

Meaning of this message:

```
  This message conveys the server's certificate chain to the client.

  The certificate MUST be appropriate for the negotiated cipher
  suite's key exchange algorithm and any negotiated extensions.
```

I don't understand the meaning of:

> The certificate MUST be appropriate for the negotiated cipher
>     suite's key exchange algorithm and any negotiated extensions.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Which parts are you having trouble with? I assume you know what certificates and ciphers are?

Comment: @Elias edited the question..the last part actually.

Comment: Okay, but what is your actual question? What is a certificate chain?

Comment: still not clear hat you exactly don't understand. Don't you understand what it means what a certificate is, what a chain is, when a certificate is appropriate for a cipher or which part exactly?

Comment: @Elias Yes and the part below stating the cert MUST be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [certificate chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_chains_and_cross-certification) is just a list of certificates each certifying the next so that you can start at some certificate you trust and conclude that the certificate for the server is valid.

Appropriate is a little difficult to explain in detail but if you look at [sample certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Sample_X.509_certificates) you will notice that the certificate includes things like

```
         X509v3 Key Usage: critical
             Digital Signature, Key Agreement
[...]

Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

And appropriate means that you can only use the certificate for the given protocols and with the right key format and so on.

Comment: Appropriate for cipher means for example that you cannot use an ECC certificate with a cipher which requires RSA key exchange, since this would require an RSA certificate.